# Dynamically created link button event not firing after page index change

Tags: asp.net

I have dynamically created link buttons in grid view and assigning event for it,

```
lb.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButtonClicked);
```

Event is not firing if I change page index change (on click of '2' below grid view) and click on link button present in grid view.

It is working fine if I do not change the page index i.e. without clicking on '2' of grid view, clicking on link button present in grid view

I am not able to find out reason for this. Please help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are  you attaching the event handler in the isPostback scope?

Comment: yes I am calling Bingridview method in isPostBack and also in onInit method, which internally calls gridview_RowdataBound where I am attaching event to link button

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create the linkbutton inside markup in a grid template column.

if you have to do it in code, try to unsubscribe the event handler then subscribe again:

```
lb.Click -= new EventHandler(LinkButtonClicked);
lb.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButtonClicked);
```